# How to handle multiple threads, single outcome in a functional way?

Tags: multithreading, functional-programming

This is not a 'pure' functional question as it involves side-effects. I have a function that may take 10 seconds, say to complete. The function generates data in a database (for example). If it is run twice at the same time it will create duplicate data. Lets say that the function can be triggered by clicking a button in the browser. If two people click within seconds of each other then the function can be running twice concurrently.

In Java and similar systems I would use synchronise on a semaphore. In Node or Django I can take advantage of the single threading to drop parallel runs.

```
running = False

def long_running_process():
  global running

  # only run once
  if running: return

  try:
    running = True
    .... go to it ...
  finally:
    running = False
```

The requirement in Python for a global reference is a clear hint that this function requires state - and so is imperative by nature.

So, to my questions.

1. How do the 'pure' functional programs that demand immutability handle this problem?
2. And how could I implement that in Python (for example)?
3. Is my best option to use a reactive Python library?

I already know that the Haskell people will tell me to create a state Monad, but how would Clojure or Elixir or ... handle it?

Comment: If the results must be computed once and kept forever, then how about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.

Comment: Good thought JimN, but a bit restricting. In the code that prompted my question I am going out and looking for files that need to be ingested in the database. It's a classic case of some push and some polling depending on whether the producer knows about the consumer.

Comment: Clojure has "software transactional memory" (STM) -- simple cases involve a combination of `dosync` and `ref` (e.g., this article: http://sw1nn.com/blog/2012/04/11/clojure-stm-what-why-how/) . but also -- don't give your db short shrift -- you could implement this sort of consistency at the database level using transactions

Comment: A good approach to wrap the complex to simplify use. I can see the jvm roots. Using database transactions to provide a similar approach is a good idea for non-Clojure when the operation is database-centric. Not sure how I work this with Mongo, but that doesn't matter as the question was about approaches, not specific systems. I suspect that there is nothing as simple as the imperative approach for this sort of problem.